# Proxy not hitting in Nuxt Axios causing CORS

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I am receiving following CORS error

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://gw.bilinfo.net/listingapi/api/export' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

My Nuxt.config.js looks like this:

```
  proxy: {
    '/listingapi/api/export/': {
      target: 'https://gw.bilinfo.net/',
      pathRewrite: { '^/listingapi/api/export/': '' },
      changeOrigin: true
    }
  },

  axios: {
    proxy: true,
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000', // Used as fallback if no runtime config is provided
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  },
```

My data fetching component looks like this:

```
  async fetch() {
    const data = await this.$axios.$get(
      'https://gw.bilinfo.net/listingapi/api/export',
      {
        credentials: true,
        auth: {
          username: 'XXXXXXX',
          password: 'XXXXXXX'
        }
      }
    )
    this.biler = data.Vehicles
  },
```

Everything works fine on refresh, but clicking around the website, gives a CORS error an data disappears. Somehow I am not hitting the proxy, but I can't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

while proxying you have to call  it below way

```
  async fetch() {
    const data = await this.$axios.$get(
      '/listingapi/api/export',
      {
        credentials: true,
        auth: {
          username: 'XXXXXXX',
          password: 'XXXXXXX'
        }
      }
    )
    this.biler = data.Vehicles
  }
```

Below proxy pass code means whenever you want to hit `https://gw.bilinfo.net/Example` API URL than you have to call it `/listingapi/api/export/Example`

```
  proxy: {
    '/listingapi/api/export/': {
      target: 'https://gw.bilinfo.net/',
      pathRewrite: { '^/listingapi/api/export/': '' },
      changeOrigin: true
    }
  },
```

Basically, what you add as pathRewrite will be replaced with the target URL.
Hope this will help!!